# How to fill NAs with LOCF by factors in data frame, split by country

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data, r-factor

I have the following data frame (simplified) with the country variable as a factor and the value variable has missing values:

```
country value
AUT     NA
AUT     5
AUT     NA
AUT     NA
GER     NA
GER     NA
GER     7
GER     NA
GER     NA
```

The following generates the above data frame:

```
data <- data.frame(country=c("AUT", "AUT", "AUT", "AUT", "GER", "GER", "GER", "GER", "GER"), value=c(NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7, NA, NA))
```

Now, I would like to replace the NA values in each country subset using the method last observation carried forward (LOCF). I know the command `na.locf` in the **zoo** package. `data <- na.locf(data)` would give me the following data frame:

```
country value
AUT     NA
AUT     5
AUT     5
AUT     5
GER     5
GER     5
GER     7
GER     7
GER     7
```

However, ***the function should only be used on the individual subsets split by the country***. The following is the output I would need:

```
country value
AUT     NA
AUT     5
AUT     5
AUT     5
GER     NA
GER     NA
GER     7
GER     7
GER     7
```

I can't think of an easy way to implement it. Before starting with for-loops, I was wondering if anyone has any idea as to how to solve this.

Many thanks!!

Comment: You might get a quicker response if you edited your question to include a reasonable test data structure.

Comment: You want [zoo::na.locf()](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/zoo/docs/na.locf) !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a `ddply` solution. Try this

```
library(plyr)
ddply(DF, .(country), na.locf)
  country value
1     AUT  <NA>
2     AUT     5
3     AUT     5
4     AUT     5
5     GER  <NA>
6     GER  <NA>
7     GER     7
8     GER     7
9     GER     7
```

**Edit**
From `ddply` help you can find that

```
.variables:  variables to split data frame by, 
as quoted variables, a formula or character vector.
```

so another alternatives to get what you want are:

```
ddply(DF, "country", na.locf)
ddply(DF, ~country, na.locf)
```

note that replacing `.variables` with `DF$variable` is not allowed, that's why you got an error when doing this.

`DF` is your data.frame

Comment: Amazing, thanks! Exactly what I needed. I tried `ddply` before, using `ddply(DF, DF$country, na.locf)` and that didn't work. What is the difference in using the `.()` notation?

Answer (score 16):

A modern version of the `ddply` solution is to use the package `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
  group_by(county) %>% 
  mutate(value = na.locf(value, na.rm = F))
```

Comment: +1 for the dplyr version. @Gregor, note that you need to add `na.rm = F`  to the `na.locf()` call. Otherwise this throws an error.

Comment: is there a way to do this for more than one column at once?

Comment: @RafaelMartins See `?mutate_at`

Answer (score 8):

The tidyverse way, albeit not using locf, is:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
    group_by(country) %>% 
    fill(value)

Source: local data frame [9 x 2]
Groups: country [2]

country value
(fctr) (dbl)
1     AUT    NA
2     AUT     5
3     AUT     5
4     AUT     5
5     GER    NA
6     GER    NA
7     GER     7
8     GER     7
9     GER     7
```

Answer (score 6):

Split the `data.frame` with `by` and use `na.locf` on the subsets:

```
do.call(rbind,by(data,data$country,na.locf))
```

If you would like to remove the row names:

```
do.call(rbind,unname(by(data,data$country,na.locf)))
```

Comment: Thanks, that works as well. However, I would have to rename the row names again to `seq_len(nrow(data))`. Therefore, I chose the above answer. However, your solution might be computationally faster, since `ddply` seems to be quite slow with large datasets.

Answer (score 4):

If speed is a consideration then this `unstack`/`stack` solution is about 4 to 6 times faster than the others on my system although it does entail a slightly longer line of code:

```
stack(lapply(unstack(data, value ~ country), na.locf, na.rm = FALSE))
```

Another approach is:

```
transform(data, value = ave(value, country, FUN = na.locf0))
```

Answer (score 4):

You simply need to split by country, then a do either a [zoo::na.locf()](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/zoo/docs/na.locf) or na.fill, filling to the right.
Here is an example explicitly showing the three-component arg syntax of na.fill:

```
library(plyr)
library(zoo)

data <- data.frame(country=c("AUT", "AUT", "AUT", "AUT", "GER", "GER", "GER", "GER", "GER"), value=c(NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7, NA, NA))

# The following is equivalent to na.locf
na.fill.right <- function(...) { na.fill(..., list(left=NA,interior=NA,right="extend")) }

ddply(data, .(country), na.fill.right)

  country value
1     AUT  <NA>
2     AUT     5
3     AUT     5
4     AUT     5
5     GER  <NA>
6     GER  <NA>
7     GER     7
8     GER     7
9     GER     7
```

Comment: @Gregor, so OP also wanted to split by country, I missed that and the `na.locf` mention, they were buried in the third paragraph. Works perfectly now. Normally the title and first paragraph should specify the question, I don't see why you didn't fix those up, I just did now. Any of you could and should have corrected that in the last 1.5 years. You can remove your downvote now.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little late to this conversation, but here is a `data.table` way, which will be much faster for larger data sets:

```
library(zoo)
library(data.table)

# Convert to data table
setDT(data)

data[, value := na.locf(value, na.rm = FALSE), by = country]

data
   country  value
1:     AUT     NA
2:     AUT      5
3:     AUT      5
4:     AUT      5
5:     GER     NA
6:     GER     NA
7:     GER      7
8:     GER      7
9:     GER      7

# And if you want to convert "data" back to a data frame...
setDF(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

A combination of the packages **dplyr** and **imputeTS** can do the job.

```
library(dplyr)
library(imputeTS)
data %>% group_by(country) %>% 
mutate(value = na.locf(value, na.remaining="keep"))
```

With the na.remaining parameter of the na.locf function of **imputeTS** you have additionally the option to choose, what to do with the trailing NAs.

These are the options:

- "keep" - return the series with NAs
- "rm" - remove remaining NAs
- "mean" - replace remaining NAs by overall mean
- "rev" - perform nocb / locf from the reverse direction

By choosing "mean" you would for example get a result with 7 for every GER in the specific example.